# Is it possible with Linear Regression that the p-value is low, but the coefficient is high when the explanatory variables are standardized?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Let's suppose that the explanatory variables are standardized, so they are on the same scale. In this case, if I understand correctly, the coefficients of each feature determine whether the attribute is relevant or not.
Is my conclusion true? Or can it happen that a coefficient of a variable is high but based on its p-value the variable is not relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can get much more complicated than that in cases where you almost have colinearity.  There are probably better examples, but try this in R with some numbers I just invented

```
> x1 <- c(-1, -0.51, -0.11, 0.11, 0.52, 1.0)
> x2 <- c(-1, -0.51, -0.12, 0.12, 0.51, 1.0)
> y <-  c(-1, -0.50, -0.10, 0.10, 0.50, 1.0)
> fit <- lm(y ~ x1+x2)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)

Residuals:
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
-0.005201  0.008268  0.009765 -0.006011 -0.015776  0.008955 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.001877   0.005720  -0.328    0.764
x1           1.126269   0.812855   1.386    0.260
x2          -0.133347   0.813761  -0.164    0.880

Residual standard error: 0.01361 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9998,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9996 
F-statistic:  6798 on 2 and 3 DF,  p-value: 3.277e-06
```

Each of $x_1$ and $x_2$ is very close to $y$ and on virtually the same scale, so on its own would make a very good predictor of $y$ with a coefficient very near $1$.

But crudely looking at the $p$ values on the right might suggest neither coefficient is significantly different from zero in the multiple regression, while the sign on the coefficient of $x_2$ is in fact negative when its relationship with $y$ looks obviously positive.